# Accessing .add on bootstrap tags-input where page has multiple inputs?

Tags: bootstrap-tags-input

I am still very new to JS, jQuery, and Ajax. I do not know the proper way to go about this. I have a page that lists products, and my job is to add the ability for the users to add tags to each product in page with the listing. So in our table that shows the products, I've added the input field with an ID of tags_#productId (so tags_10093) so that each field will be unique.

Now, I need to be able to call .on(beforeItemAdd...) to each field. On each tag add, I will be calling a function in a controller that will store the created tag to a database. I will also be using this same concept to populate the field with tags already assigned to that product on page load.

What I'm having trouble with is deciding how to write this call. The inputs are rendered in a foreach loop based on the product. Would it be "Decent", to render the Ajax script in the same foreach loop so that it can grab the correct class at the same time?